# JQuery - How can I check that onclick event already called for a button?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have an input (type: button), and I want to call for that an onclick event. But sometimes I added the input button later, and then I have to call again the event. So I have an input button with 2 onclick event. How can I check that onclick event already called for that?

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: __But sometimes I added the input button later__ what do you mean by this?

Comment: What you mean by "I want to call for that an onclick event"? Are you using a jquery `.click()` or `.on()` api? If yes, then you are not **calling** and `onclick()`, you are just hanging a function inside the `onclick()`. You will need to hang this handler to every new button!

Comment: Sometimes I have to add the input button into a form later with ajax.

Comment: Use a single delegated event on a parent element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter=0;
$("#btn").onClick(function(){
    counter+=1;
    // do some
});
```

then u can check the value of counter:

```
if (counter>0){
    alert("clicked before");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding event handlers again for dynamically generated elements, you can [delegate the event handler](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to a static (*preferable the closest parent element which is not dynamically generated*) parent element using the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method.

For example:

```
$(document).on("click",":button",function(){});
```

Will work with the buttons you generate dynamically in future as well. So no need to bind events again which is causing the issue for you.